# arm-eabi-none undefined reference to memset error for LPC2148

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, linker-errors

Whenever I try to use any array parameters I'm getting the `memset()` error. Also, I cant use `sprintf()` statement even after including standard libraries, what are the parameters should I include in the makefile to link or fix this `memset()` and `sprintf()` reference error.

`memset()` [error full code with lpc214x linker file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IINFg_tO7OhmqBUHw_mPIV3S_FXYUz8H)

My target board is LPC2148(arm7-TDMA based)
here is the `Makefile`

```
ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi

COPS = -Wall -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding 

all : main.hex main.bin main.elf

clean :
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.hex
    rm -f *.elf

crt0.o : crt0.S
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc -c crt0.S

main.o : main.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -c main.c -o main.o

main.elf : lpc2148.ld crt0.o main.o 
    $(ARMGNU)-ld crt0.o main.o -T lpc2148.ld -o main.elf

main.bin : main.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy main.elf -O binary main.bin

main.hex : main.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy main.elf -O ihex main.hex
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Instead of `arm-none-eabi-ld` try with `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using `arm-none-eabi-ld` during linking operation which is unable to link to standard `libgcc` for the target processor.

Please modify the `Makefile` and use `arm-none-eabi-gcc` to link your various object files.

As, you are using a custom startup file you also need to pass `-nostartfiles` option to linker.

The modified Makefile is below:

```
all : main.hex main.bin main.elf

clean :
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.hex
    rm -f *.elf

crt0.o : crt0.S
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc -c crt0.S

main.o : main.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -c main.c -o main.o

main.elf : lpc2148.ld crt0.o main.o 
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc crt0.o main.o -T lpc2148.ld -o main.elf -nostartfiles

main.bin : main.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy main.elf -O binary main.bin

main.hex : main.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy main.elf -O ihex main.hex
```

Comment: Getting this error
arm-none-eabi-gcc crt0.o main.o -T lpc2148.ld -o main.elf
crt0.o: In function `_mainCRTStartup':
(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o:/build/newlib-OTNHfJ/newlib-2.4.0.20160527/build/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm/../../../../libgloss/arm/crt0.S:180: first defined here
crt0.o: In function `_mainCRTStartup':
(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `_mainCRTStartup'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o:/build/newlib-OTNHfJ/newlib-2.4.0.20160527/build/arm-none-eabi/libgloss/arm/

Comment: @SiddharthSidhu For `main.elf:` add `-nostartfiles` at the end of line `$(ARMGNU)-gcc crt0.o main.o -T lpc2148.ld -o main.elf`

Comment: Sorry, Its working now Thank you very much,
can you please explain the flow of linking process

Comment: @SiddharthSidhu It should work. I am using Ubuntu, and I am getting this error only when I remove `-nostartfiles` from that rule of `main.elf` and then do a `make clean` and `make`. If I use `-nostartfiles` in the rule of target `main.elf` and do a `make clean` and `make` I don't see any error.

Comment: @SiddharthSidhu You can read about whole compilation process [here](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html) and in brief [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compiling-a-c-program-behind-the-scenes/).

Comment: Thank you it was really helpful, if you have any good source to learn about usage of arm compiler instructions can you share link here i cannot find valuable information by googling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162788/discussion-between-siddharth-sidhu-and-gaurav).

Comment: `memset` is in `libc`. Adding it manually allows arm-none-eabi-ld to link successfully.